# A sentence within a sentence

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

> Rep. Lauren Boebert has mocked philanthropist Bill Gates' wish to move toward a future in which people eat only synthetic meat—by sharing an image of a steak *that a New York butcher claims was lifted from its website.*

It's a Newsweek [article.](http://Rep.%20Lauren%20Boebert%20has%20mocked%20philanthropist%20Bill%20Gates%27%20wish%20to%20move%20toward%20a%20future%20in%20which%20people%20eat%20only%20synthetic%20meat%E2%80%94by%20sharing%20an%20image%20of%20a%20steak%20that%20a%20New%20York%20butcher%20claims%20was%20lifted%20from%20its%20website.) I understand what it means but the structure of italic part is not familiar.
I think the above is overlapped sentences and the primitive form would be *that was lifted from its(a butcher's) website*. The problem is the isertion of whole sentence *a New York butcher claims* between a subject *that* and a verb *was*.

Is it possible? Yes it should be because it's an article of a global media. How is it possible? I have never seen an example like that in any English grammar books. Is it a broken sentence which is colloquial and friendly?

Comment: No - there's ***not*** a "whole sentence" being inserted here. There's an optional "adjectival" ***that-*** clause modifying the existing noun phrase ***an image of a steak***. The adjectival clause doesn't have a subject, so it's not a sentence (that would be *A New York butcher claims **that image of a steak** was lifted from its website*).

Comment: I assume you don't have a problem with *I read the letter that she wrote*. So you shouldn't have a problem with *I read the letter that she claimed was written by her mother.*

Comment: "That a New York butcher claims was lifted from its website" is a relative clause modifying "image of a steak". Note that "that" is not subject, but a subordinator functioning as a 'marker'. Thus we have: "a steak [that a New York butcher claims [___ was lifted from its website]]", where gap functions as subject of the embedded "was lifted" clause and has "image of a steak" as antecedent.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is the whole **that a New York butcher claims was lifted from its website** an adjectival clause? If so are there 2 verbs which are **claims** and **was** in 1 clause?

Comment: Well, as @BillJ says, it's **a relative clause modifying "image of a steak"**. So if you've got to choose between "noun, verb, adjective" I suppose it's the last of those categories (where "image of a steak" is obviously a ***noun***, and the *actual* "primary verb" in your cited text is ***mocked***).

Answer (score 2):

> *Rep. Lauren Boebert has mocked philanthropist Bill Gates' wish to move*
> *toward a future in which people eat only synthetic meat—by sharing an*
> *image of a steak* [*that a New York butcher claims was lifted from its*
> *website*].

The bracketed element "that a New York butcher claims was lifted from its website" is a relative clause modifying "image of a steak". Note that "that" is not the subject of the relative clause, but a subordinator functioning as a 'marker'.

Thus we have the NP: "an image of a steak [that a New York butcher claims [___ was lifted from its website]]", where gap ___ functions as subject of the embedded "was lifted" clause and has "image of a steak" as antecedent.

The outer brackets surround the relative clause and the inner ones surround the embedded clause that has gap___ as its subject.

Comment: What is the object of **claims**?

Comment: @SHINJaeGuk "Claims" does not have an object.

Comment: Can a transitive verb exist without an object? Or do you think it is an intrasitive one?

Comment: "Claims" is intransitive here. Note that the relativised item ('gap') is not object of "claims" but subject of the embedded "was lifted" clause. We understand that a New York butcher claims [an image of a steak was lifted from its website]. The bracketed clause is **complement** of "claims". OK now?